# Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown by WorldServer class

Tags: c#

Here is my code `WorldServer.cs`:

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string header;
    public Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public int connectionId;
}

namespace Server
{
    public class WorldServer
    {
        private Character character = new Character();

        void Test()
        {
            character.UpdateCharacterState();
        }

        public void Broadcast()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We in Broadcast");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Character.cs`:

```
public class Character : WorldServer
{
    public void UpdateCharacterState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("State:");
        Broadcast();
    }
}
```

And when i try to run my code i receive the following error:

> Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

I have one base class `WorldServer` and one that extends it `Character`. I have to call from `WorldServer` class the method `UpdateCharacterState` and from `Character` class the `Broadcast` method which is declared in `WorldServer` class. Is it possible and how?
Can you tell me where is my mistake and how can i fix it?

Comment: Every time you construct an instance of `Character`, which inherits from `WorldServer`, you construct another `Character`, which inherits from `WorldServer`, so it needs to construct a `Character`, which inherits from ... you see it?

Comment: I got your point but i'm very new to `C#`. Can you make an answer showing me how to make this construct ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand what you want to accomplish so it won't be possible for me to implement it.

Comment: I would like to access `UpdateCharacterState` from `WorldServer` and `Broadcast` from `Character` class.

Comment: If Character inherits WorldServer, why does WorldSever need a private Character at all??

Comment: Why does character inherit from worldserver?

Comment: So you want a base class use a method present in its inherited class. Smell fishy.

Comment: I'm really not sure how to make these two methods `UpdateCharacterState ` and `Broadcast` to be able to call each other even if they are in different files. That's all i want to achieve.

Comment: There are [many questions about this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Exception+of+type+%27System.StackOverflowException%27+was+thrown). Do any of them answer your question?

Comment: @TonyStark One way to do that would be with events.

Comment: @Gusman can you show me how and are events the best approach for such thing ?

Comment: did not read comments...can you publish the full code? character have a constructor? it smells like endless recursive call...

Comment: Gusman had the best question here yet: Why does character inherot from worldserver? It's like having a Lion inherit Furniture. Of course it's possible, but it doesn't make much sense when you read only the class names, does it? When a class inherits another class, it means it's a more specific kind of whatever is the base class - a table inherits furniture, a lion inherits animals. How is a character is a kind of world server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this will work.... however it's not very good OOP, but I'll leave that up to your journey (and future questions) as you learn how to code.

Anyway...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = new WorldServer();

            server.Test();
        }
    }

    public class JsonData
    {
        public string header;
        public Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public int connectionId;
    }


    public class WorldServer
    {
        private Character character = new Character();

        public void Test() {
            character.UpdateCharacterState(this);
        }

        public void Broadcast(){
            Console.WriteLine("We in Broadcast");
        }
    }



    public class Character 
    {
        public void UpdateCharacterState(WorldServer server)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("State:");

            server.Broadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the takeaway for you is to research classes vs instances and what that actually means. The modified code I've given introduces you to a new concept (potentially) for you known as "dependency injection" which is a good way to reference other object types.... try to limit your use of inheritance as much as possible.

Good luck and keep learning!

Comment: You are the man! All i needed to see and get the idea was this line `public void UpdateCharacterState(WorldServer server)`. I changed my approach by putting worldserver and character into two different namespaces. Thank you once again.

Comment: Can you please give me any good link where i can research more about these classes vs instances ?

Comment: To be a good programmer you need to research your own stuff (I do it *every day* and I started when I was 15, now 41). I'm happy to help you through an example like the one you posted, but not googling yourself is a little lazy.... anyway, just this once  :)  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-class-object-and-class-instance

Comment: Got it! Thank you once again. So if i understanded correctly with this `character.UpdateCharacterState(this)` i'm basicly sending the instance of `WorldServer` into `Character` class calling `UpdateCharacterState` and the instance is the first parameter of `UpdateCharacterState` method. Correct ?

Comment: You go it mate :)